# Chartjs: Is it possible to hide the data labels on the axis but show up on the graph on hover?

Tags: chart.js

Currently my graph looks something like this 
[chartjs graph with x-axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5jzl.png)

Looking to remove the X axis data labels yet show the time value on hover (on a data point)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Chart.js version 2. Try `ticks display false` in the `options`  section

---

```
//...
  options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
//...
```

---

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7o3m81zt/